# How to round an integer to a larger number which is divisible by 5 using javaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have such a problem, I want to round the given numbers to the nearest high number that is divisible by 5.
For example:

```js
let num = 12;
function round5(arg) {
    console.log(Math.round(arg / 5) * 5)
}

round5(num)
```

In this case, I want the result to be 15.
What would be the best solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use [Math.ceil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) which will round up

```
function round5(arg) {
    console.log(Math.ceil(arg / 5) * 5)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) will round to the closest integer so 2.4 becomes 2. You want to use [ceil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) which always round up so 2.4 becomes 3

```js
let num = 12;
function round5(arg) {
    console.log(Math.ceil(arg / 5) * 5)
}

round5(num)
```